# How can I measure diagonal distance points?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi, distance, measurement

I can compute horizontal and vertical points, but I cant figure out how to compute distance using diagonal points. Can someone help me with this.

here's the code for my horizontal and vertical measuring:

```
private float ComputeDistance(float point1, float point2) 
{
        float sol1 = point1 - point2;
        float sol2 = (float)Math.Abs(Math.Sqrt(sol1 * sol1));

        return sol2;
}

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        _endPoint.X = e.X;
        _endPoint.Y = e.Y;

        if (ComputeDistance(_startPoint.X, _endPoint.X) <= 10)
        {
            str = ComputeDistance(_startPoint.Y, _endPoint.Y).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            if (ComputeDistance(_startPoint.Y, _endPoint.Y) <= 10)
            {
                str = ComputeDistance(_startPoint.X, _endPoint.X).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Assuming that the _startPoint has been already set.

[image]

In this image the diagonal point is obviously wrong.

Comment: Math.Sqrt(sol1 * sol1) == Math.Abs(sol1)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use Pythagoras' theorem.

```
d = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(end.x - start.x, 2) + Math.Pow(end.y - start.y, 2))
```

Comment: This one's a Pythagorean, Wait I will try this one.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're looking for the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) formula.

> In mathematics, the Euclidean distance or Euclidean metric is the "ordinary" distance between two points that one would measure with a ruler, and is given by the Pythagorean formula.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that there are actually many ways of calculating distance and that the Euclidean distance is probably the one wanted here.

Answer (score 3):

Well you might take a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Much time later... I'd like to add that you could use some built-in functionality of .NET:

```
using System.Windows;

Point p1 = new Point(x1, y1);
Point p2 = new Point(x2, y2);
Vector v = p1 - p2;
double distance = v.Length;
```

or simply:

```
static double Distance(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2)
{
    return (new Point(x1, y1) - new Point(x2, y2)).Length;
}
```